# Is there a Visual Studio functionality for browsing through overloaded methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a huge project. There are some methods which call their own overloads to set a default value, instead of just appending the default value in the methods' parameters.

I'm curious if there is a function to search for all the overloads so I can quickly traverse them all.

Example:

From this

```cs
public static Options getContext()
{
    // default value false
    return getContext(false);
    // code
}

public static Options getContext(bool forceRefresh)
{
    // code
}
```

To this

```cs
// also default value false
public static Options getContext(bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: Do note that removing an overload in favor of a default value is a breaking change; default values get compiled at the call site.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I did not know this. So this means the value gets compiled at the place you call the function/method, like an other controller file, instead of the same file inside the helper. I'm not sure how this will impact the project.

Comment: you might have `Options (*f)() = getContext` (either direct assignment like here, or passing function parameters or storing pointers to function in containers) which whill will stop compiling if you remove the no args overload.